# How do you add resize functionality to flex components?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm creating a flex drag and drop interface of sorts that will have a range of different components. Is there a standard way of adding resize handlers to a component or does the component need to be overridden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found quite a useful example that is easy to implement. It gives support for changing cursors, setting bounds, rotation and fixed aspect ratio. I think its worth a look for anyone needing to add resize support.

https://github.com/marc-hughes/ObjectHandles/tree/master/flex-object-handles

The above link is a flex project download. Import the flex project and run the MoveAndResize.mxml example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean front-end resizing?
Senocular wrote an excellent transform class for that:
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformtool/

http://www.senocular.com/demo/TransformToolAS3/TransformTool.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for flex. It needs the flash.display.sprite class which flex doesn't have. =/

Comment: But, it has been adapted: http://joelhooks.com/2008/04/20/using-the-senocular-as3-transformtool-in-flex/